# some questions about using mouse (move event) to draw lines with quintus engine

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have some questions about using mouse (move event) to draw lines with quintus engine. Can someone help me ?

Here's the thing.
I want to draw lines with mouse movement in the quintus scene,my code is like:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
        var Q = window.Q = new Quintus()
        .include("Sprites, Scenes,  2D, Anim,  UI")
        .setup({maximize:true});

        Q.Sprite.extend("Balloon",{
            init:function(p){
                this._super(p,{
                    x:100+Math.floor(Math.random()*12)*100,
                    y:200,
                    sheet:"balloon",
                    sprite:"balloon",
                    frame:Math.floor(Math.random()*12),
                    points:[[-50,50],[-50,-50],[50,-50],[50,50]]
                }); 
            },
        });

        Q.scene("start",function(stage){
            stage.insert(new Q.Balloon());
        });

        Q.load("balloon.png",function(){
            Q.sheet("balloon","balloon.png",{sx:0,sy:1,cols:12,tilew:100,tileh:100,frames:12});
            Q.stageScene("start");
        });

        var canvas = document.getElementById("quintus");
        canvas.setAttribute("width",  "1920px");
        canvas.setAttribute("height",  "555px");
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.top = "0px";
        canvas.style.left = "0px";
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


        var listener_move = function(event){
            console.log(ctx);
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(ctx.lastX, ctx.lastY);
            ctx.lineTo(event.clientX,event.clientY);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.lastX = event.clientX;
            ctx.lastY = event.clientY;
        };

        var listener_down = function(event){
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.lastX = event.clientX;
            ctx.lastY = event.clientY;
            document.body.addEventListener("mousemove",listener_move,false);
        };

        var listener_up = function(event){
            document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove",listener_move,false);
        };

        document.body.addEventListener("mousedown",listener_down,false);

        document.body.addEventListener("mouseup",listener_up,false);
    });
```

however, I get my ballon sprite ,and my log can capture the event.clientX and event.clientY , but there is no lines appear on the screen.  I don't know why.

Can somebody help me ???

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the quintus engine, but your mouse events and drawing code looks OK. So I think that perhaps the quintus engine is erasing and drawing on top of your ctx output, via animation-frame or some such functionality.

(Oh, and also make sure that the html canvas really has the id set to "quintus" )

Comment: I've checked the Quintus engines source code, and yes the game loop is started by the Q.stageScene, after which the canvas is redrawn repeatedly via requestAnimationFrame, which means your drawings get discarded.

Comment: thanks a lot! I see the reason now .I wonder if there is a way to add my customized mouse event into quintus or is there any other game engine support such functionality?

Comment: For simple tests you can probably call Q.pauseGame() in your mouseDown event handler, then Q.unpauseGame() in a mouseUp event handler. The more complex way to handle this is to override the renderloop (Q.gameLoop), however as you still need to clear the canvas to animate your ballon sprites, this means that you would have to keep an array of all the mouse coordinates, so that you can redraw the complete sequence on each gameLoop iteration.

Comment: As an alternative, you could add a second transparent canvas on top of the first one and draw your mouse trails separately on this second canvas.